# Build tools version 24.0.0 installed but gradle don't see it

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

i have a problem when i trying to compile my project. Gradle claims that i have not install build tools version 24.0.0 but it installed as you see in the screenshot. Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3przD.png)

Comment: Can you click on "Launch stand alone SDK Manager" and post a screen shot?

Comment: post your gradle code

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qxIy.png

Comment: Gradle file is ok because my friend can compile this project on his computer. Something is wrong with my android studio probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. My ANDROID_HOME variable was wrong. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project then try to build it.

To Clean in topBar of your android studio: Build -> Clean project.

Comment: Gradle file is ok because my friend can compile this project on his computer. Something is wrong with my android studio probably

Comment: which android studio version you and your friend is using? Is it same? I don't know why but sometimes it happens due to this reason, try to match your version.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your Android Studio Cache and Restart Android Studio.
To clear cache, Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: without effect too

Comment: I have windows ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project, then install lower version of build tools, and then invalidate cache and restart.